# Calculate MRR Kpi without monthly invoices

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate mrr for each month.
The DB table 'boxes' looks like this:

| project_id | product_id | payment_method_id | price | interval | booked_at | canceled_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 19.00 | 1 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 39.00 | 1 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | 2020-11-05 19:10:27 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 39.00 | 12 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | 2020-11-05 19:10:27 |

Payment-Interval is in months. I need to show in KPI dashboard the mrr.
Currently I have this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(booked_at, '%Y-%m') AS period, sum(price)
   FROM
project_boxes
   GROUP BY period;
```

The problem with the above query is that it doesn't show between months MRR and doesn't work with canceled boxes.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That’s a lot of jargon for a short question

Comment: What is a *MRR*?